# Powershell - query servers with roles installed

Tags: powershell-2.0

I have a txt file with all the server names.

I want to query each server in the txt to see if RDS is installed. So far it works fine. But the export needs to have servername and the installed role. how can I pass the servername to the output file.
At the moment it is querying but only the installed. so with a 100 servers who really can tell which server has it installed and which doesnt>>>> PLEase help

```
Import-Module ServerManager

Get-Content W:\AllWindows.txt | ForEach-Object {Get-WindowsFeature -Name Remote-Desktop-Services} | Format-Table -Auto -wrap | Out-File -FilePath $csvfile
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Get-Content W:\AllWindows.txt | ForEach-Object { @(($_), (Get-WindowsFeature -Name Remote-Desktop-Services)) } | Format-Table -Auto -wrap | Out-File -FilePath $csvfile
```

Answer (score 0):

I have worked it out:

```
Get-Content W:\windows2012.csv | Foreach-Object {{Get-WindowsFeature | where-object {$_.Installed -eq $True} | Export-Csv -Path "W:\output\$_.txt"}
```